# force jspm to install newest version

Tags: node.js, jspm, package.json

I'm trying to update all my jspm dependencies to the newest version,
the only "solution" I found is "jspm update", but this only installs the version,
which is defined in the package.json
Isn't there anyway to automatically update the packages to the really newest version and settings the new version number in the package.json?

Cedric

Comment: I'm confused. The jspm dependencies should be installed in the jspm config.js and not the packages.json. Do you want to update even to the lastest major versions or just minor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jspm uses semver notation for updating the packages. Please make sure you are using the [notation](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) correctly.

For instance, if you run `Jspm update` with a `package@1.0.2` package definition on the packages.json, the package will not be updated to a new version because the version is locked for 1.0.2.